# Can I manage guest VMs in vSphere free using Ansible without vCenter?

Tags: ansible, vsphere

Seems to me that most of the existing Ansible modules require vCenter.
For example [guest_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html) has required parameter vcenter_hostname.
The question is - is there an ability to manage 2-3 vSphere hosts using Ansible?
I need creating virtual environments(virtual networks, guest VMs, load balancing endpoints).

I also considered Hyper-v but it doesn't have Ansible modules. Direct powershell management considered as a last resort for Hyper-v.

Comment: VMware does not enable its API in free versions of their products, so you can't do it with Ansible modules, which rely on the API. Besides, "I want to play with something, but I'm not sure with what" does not seem on-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do things that are allowed by free license.

There's a hint in [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html):

> For standalone ESXi hosts, ha-datacenter should be used as the datacenter name

I use `vsphere_guest` without any problems with standalone hypervisors with the following parameters filled in:

```
- vsphere_guest:
    vcenter_hostname: "{{ esxi_ip_or_dns }}" # ip address of hypervisor
    esxi:
      datacenter: ha-datacenter
      hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}" # name shown in hypervisor console
    username: "{{ esxi_username }}"
    password: "{{ esxi_password }}"
```

But keep in mind, that many useful features are blocked in free license. For example, you can't clone VMs without vCenter license.

Comment: but what about vCenter(vcenter_hostname)? I believe, It also requires a license

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by `vCenter(vcenter_hostname)`. In my example I showed how to work with standalone vSphere hypervisors without vCenter.

Comment: Konstantin, you specified parameter vcenter_hostname: "{{ esxi_ip_or_dns }}". According to documentation vcenter_hostname: The hostname of the vcenter server the module will connect to, to create the guest. As I know vcenter requires a licence. I'm not clear how did it work for you.

Comment: You can specify your esxi server ip address as `vcenter_hostname` here, I've updated my answer to make it more clear.