# How to create VM on Standalone ESXi hosts using vsphere_guest Ansible Module

Tags: linux, ansible, esxi

I am trying to create a VM on a standalone ESXi host using ansible playbook.
I saw in the following link that we can use "ha-datacenter" as the datacenter name to make ansible create VM on standalone ESXi host.

[Can I manage guest VMs in vSphere free using Ansible without vCenter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420285/can-i-manage-guest-vms-in-vsphere-free-using-ansible-without-vcenter)

I am however getting following error while trying to run the playbook
Please advise

```
Error
[Parameter Error]: 'host' should be a string with the ESX/VC url
```

Following are playbook contents

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
   - name: myuser
     prompt: Enter the UserName
     private: no
   - name: mypass
     prompt: Enter the Password
   - name: vc_name
     prompt: Enter the vCenter/ESXi HostName
     private: no
   - name: guest_name
     prompt: Enter the Guest VM Name
     private: no
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
   - name: Create a VM
     delegate_to: localhost
     vsphere_guest:
#       vcenter_hostname: '{{vc_name}}'
       esxi:
         datacenter: ha-datacenter
         hostname: '{{vc_name}}'
       username: '{{myuser}}'
       password: '{{mypass}}'
       validate_certs: no
       guest: '{{guest_name}}'
       state: powered_on
       vm_extra_config:
         vcpu.hotadd: yes
         mem.hotadd:  yes
         notes: This is a test VM created using Ansible

       vm_disk:
         disk1:
           size_gb: 100
           type: thin
           datastore: datastore1
       vm_nic:
         nic1:
           type: vmxnet3
           network: VM Network
           network_type: standard
       vm_hardware:
         memory_mb: 2048
         num_cpus: 2
         osid: rhel6_64Guest
         scsi: paravirtual
         vm_cdrom:
           type: "iso"
           iso_path: "iso/rhel6.iso"
```

Output

```
Wed Jul 26 05:35:36 ansible@ansible-2:~/vmware$ ansible-playbook vmcreate.yml
Enter the UserName: root
Enter the Password:
Enter the vCenter/ESXi HostName: 10.1.1.1
Enter the Guest VM Name: ansible-test-vm

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Create a VM] *************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: pysphere.resources.vi_exception.VIException: [Parameter Error]: 'host' should be a string with the ESX/VC url.
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_SE0C2e/ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py\", line 1879, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_SE0C2e/ansible_module_vsphere_guest.py\", line 1748, in main\n    viserver.connect(vcenter_hostname, username, password)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysphere/vi_server.py\", line 71, in connect\n    ,FaultTypes.PARAMETER_ERROR)\npysphere.resources.vi_exception.VIException: [Parameter Error]: 'host' should be a string with the ESX/VC url.\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'vmcreate.retry'.         [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Wed Jul 26 05:35:58 ansible@ansible-2:~/vmware$
```

Comment: Playbook contents in a better format.


https://pastebin.com/sQ2XMBXe

Comment: You can format code blocks at SO as well, see my edits. Why `vcenter_hostname` is commented out?

Comment: Hi Konstantin, that was the issue. I income yes vcenter_hostname and instead of ip I gave hostname of esxi and it worked

Comment: after deploying VM through Ansible how to login to vm ? I mean which user and password ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the comments:

> Why `vcenter_hostname` is commented out?

-

> that was the issue, instead of ip I gave hostname of esxi and it worked